# A zig-zag layout for my webpage

Tags: html, css

http://gunzhaxplz.com/transitions/example2/index2.html

I want my layout to look like this with variable size div tags on the left and right edges how would i style the left and right sides to do this please help
[image]

important styles i used:

```
.rightside {
margin-left:200px;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Try rephrasing the question by showing us what you want to achieve on a grid (so that we can tell where you want the boxes). Then, show us the code you've written to try and solve the problem yourself so that we may be able to point you in the right direction. A lot of people here will offer help, but prefer not to simply give away 'answers'.

Comment: well the styles i used on that page are now added to the question, the downvote was harsh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? with alternate float right's:     http://jsfiddle.net/itz2k13/CTKPJ/

```
.right{
  float: right;
}
div{
  clear: both;
}
```